# How do I separate a space-delimited string into multiple variables?

Tags: python, string, variables

I'm trying to write a program that uses Pascal's triangle to FOIL binomials. Any binomial FOILed using this method will follow a basic pattern. I already have a general idea of what to do, I just need to figure out how to separate a space-delimited string into many ints that are called by variables.

For example, I want to take this input:

```
pascalInput = raw_input("Type the full row of Pascal's triangle with numbers separated by space: ") 
#say the input is '1 3 3 1'
```

and put it into the variables:

```
pascalVal1
pascalVal2
pascalVal3
```

etc.

I don't know how I would write out how many variables I need or whatever else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more convenient if you stored your values in a list:

```
pascalVals = raw_input('...').split()
```

And then access them like this:

```
pascalVals[0]
pascalVals[1]
pascalVals[2]
```

If you want integers instead of strings, use:

```
pascalVals = [int(x) for x in raw_input('...').split()]
```

Comment: How would I use recursion to use something like `def next(row):
  newrow = [ row[k-1]+row[k]
             for k in range(1,len(row)) ]
  return [1] + newrow + [1]
def pascal(rowsleft,oldrow):
  if rowsleft > 0:
    R = next(oldrow)
    pascal(rowsleft-1,R)
list1 = [1]
list121 = [1,2,1]
pascal(3,[1,2,1])

rowsleft = exponent`

The full thing I want to do is take an equation "(x+1)^3" for example, and foil it to [(1x^3+1^0) + (3x^2+1^1) + (3x^1+1^2) + (3x^0+1^3)]

Comment: Please open a new question for this, so you can use proper code formatting. Like this you snippet is slightly illegible.

Comment: [New question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221695/use-recursion-to-foil-a-binomial)

Answer (score 0):

```
pascalVals = PascalInput.split(' ')
```

pascalVals - list of strings. For indexing write

```
some_var = pascalVals[0]
```

If you need exactly pascalVal1 vars:

```
for i in len(pascalVals):
    exec('pascalVal' + str(i+1) + ' = pascalVals[' + str(i) + ']')
```

Answer (score 0):

use map function

```
print map(int, raw_input("Type the full row of Pascal's triangle with numbers separated by space: ").split())
```