# Use recursion to FOIL a binomial

Tags: python, math, recursion

I'm trying to foil a binomial using Pascal's Triangle. I have the code:

```
def next(row):
  newrow = [ row[k-1]+row[k]
             for k in range(1,len(row)) ]
  return [1] + newrow + [1]
def pascal(rowsleft,oldrow):
  if rowsleft > 0:
    R = next(oldrow)
    pascal(rowsleft-1,R)
list1 = [1]
list121 = [1,2,1]
pascal(3,[1,2,1])
rowsleft = exponent
```

The full thing I want to do is take an equation "(x+1)^3" for example, and foil it to [(1x^3*1^0) + (3x^2*1^1) + (3x^1*1^2) + (3x^0*1^3)] with the result concatenated to: x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1

Comment: Can you provide full example of input and output you want to get? There are many ways to do what you want to do, it depends on interface you want to have.

Comment: Well, "(x+1)^3" would be the input and the program would display the output:  "x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1"

Comment: Are you aware of need for some kind of mathematical formula parser? I'm trying to figure out which part is problematic here - input or calculations themselves

Answer (score 0):

For parsing input (as I see, that is what you actually need) you can use one of those: [str.partition](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) (also check rpartition) or [str.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Examples (following assertions hold):

```
assert "a;b;c".parition(";") == ("a", ";", "b;c")
assert "a;b;c".split(";") == ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I'd use partitioning, to get part between parenthesis (by partitioning by "^"), last part of tuple I'd assume to be expotent. Then, I'd check whether first part starts with "(" and ends with ")". Now, I'd remove "(" and ")" and split whats left by "+". If "+" isn't there, I'd split by "-" and assume second part of sum as negative. Now you'd have both addends and expotent, which you can use to form output.

Comment: Ok. So when I use the exponent as row, when I pass 

`import PascalTri`
`PascalVals = PascalTri.pascal(3, [1,2,1])`
PascalVals is returned as None.

Where is my code messed up?

Comment: Got no idea, because your code is... weird. What is in PascalTri module? What EXACTLY does PascalTri.pascal take and what does it return?

Comment: [PascalTri is here(pastebin link).](http://pastebin.com/D3b7Z09n)
it takes an int (the exponent) and [1,2,1] (the starting row) and **SHOULD** return a list containing the values of the row, but instead returns None.